# Sorting y-axis sub-variables into Before, After and Post, instead of After, Before and Post

Tags: plot, stata, box

I am trying to make a boxplot im Stata where I want subvariables , under the variable "Watering_event", to be aaranged in the following order Before, After, Post.

The data looks like this in the dataset

```
Watering_event
Before
After
Post
```

Here is the command and picture how it appeals

```
graph box photosynthesis, over(watering_event, sort(watering_event)) title("Watered Plants-Main Experiment") xsize(10) ysize(10)
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5gpy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPBhE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Either `watering_event` is a string variable or it has been `encode`d alphabetically, not what you want.

If the first, then

```
label def event 1 "Before" 2 "After" 3 "Post" 
encode watering_event, gen(event) label(event)
```

If the second, then there are various fixes, one of which uses `recode`.

This code illustrates both problems and how to fix them, after which use a fixed variable for your box plots.

```
clear 
input str6 wrong1 wrong2 
"After"       1
"Before"      2
"Post"        3
end 

label def wrong2 1 After 2 Before 3 Post
label val wrong2 wrong2 

label def right 1 Before 2 After 3 Post 

encode wrong1, gen(right1) label(right)

recode wrong2 2=1 1=2, gen(right2)
label val right2 right 

list 

list, nolabel
```

Results:

```
. list 

     +-----------------------------------+
     | wrong1   wrong2   right1   right2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. |  After    After    After    After |
  2. | Before   Before   Before   Before |
  3. |   Post     Post     Post     Post |
     +-----------------------------------+

. list, nolabel 

     +-----------------------------------+
     | wrong1   wrong2   right1   right2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. |  After        1        2        2 |
  2. | Before        2        1        1 |
  3. |   Post        3        3        3 |
     +-----------------------------------+
```